# How to check if JS object implement some DOM IDL interface?

Tags: javascript, dom, specifications

[Specs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#node) say that document nodes satisfy HTMLElement IDL interface. This evaluates to `true`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a')[0] instanceof HTMLElement
```

Is that a correct way to test (by `instanceof HTMLElement`)?

Comment: Side note: A better way to write `document.querySelectorAll('a')[0]` would be `document.querySelector('a')`. :-) That way, the engine knows it can stop looking when it's found the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure *why* you want to do this, but it should work in modern browsers. It won't work in IE8 or below.

If your goal is to see whether a node is an Element or a Text node or similar, the more broadly-compatible way is to use the [`nodeType` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-111237558):

```
document.querySelector('a').nodeType === 1
```

The types are given by the DOM specs as part of the definition of the [`Node` interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247) (1 = Element).

If your goal is to test whether an element is a specific *type* of element (`HTMLAnchorElement` and so on), use [`nodeName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-F68D095) or (if you know it's an element) `tagName`. In an HTML (not XHTML) document, those are upper case tag names, e.g.

```
console.log(document.querySelector('a').nodeName); // "A"
```

Comment: I ask another question where I iterate over `node = node.parentNode` and need condition when to stop, which is `node instanceof HTMLElement`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185512/how-to-check-if-some-dom-element-in-another-dom-element-tree