# How to check if some DOM element in another DOM element tree?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, specifications

How to check if some DOM element in another DOM element tree?

For example to hide menu when you click on main page content instead of menu you can:

```
document.addEventListener(function (e) {
    var node = e.target;
    do {
        if (node.classList.contains('menu-area'))
            return;
        node = node.parentNode;
    } while (node instanceof HTMLElement);
    closeMenu();
});
```

Note that usual solution to hide menu when you click to non-menu area is `event.stopPropagation()` on menu and non-conditional `document.addEventListener()`.

I make test code with iteration loop over `node = node.parentNode` and `===` operator:

```
<style>
div {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px green dotted;
}
</style>

<div id="lvl1">
  <div id="lvl2">
    <div id="lvl3">
      Click me
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>


<script>
  var lvl1Node = document.getElementById('lvl1');
  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var node = e.target;
    do {
      if (lvl1Node === node) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Event from: " + e.target.id;
        return;
      }
      node = node.parentNode;
    } while (node instanceof HTMLElement);
  });
</script>
```

So only click inside `<div id='lvl1'>` change `<div id="result">` area. Is that right solution (according to standard)?

That jQuery/Backbone/Underscore/Mojo/etc have to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `instanceof` for this (not least because it won't work in IE8, which sadly continues to linger). Test for `===` the node where you want to stop, probably `document.body` or `document.documentElement` (the `<html>` element):

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var node = e.target;
    do {
        if (node.classList.contains('menu-area'))
            return;
        node = node.parentNode;
    } while (node !== document.documentElement);
    closeMenu();
});
```

Or as your loop has initialization, test, and "increment," it's a good match for `for`:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var node;
    for (node = e.target; node !== document.documentElement; node = node.parentNode) {
        if (node.classList.contains('menu-area')) {
            return;
        }
    }
    closeMenu();
});
```

> That jQuery/Backbone/Underscore/Mojo/etc have to this?

For what you're doing above, jQuery does, yes, in two ways:

1. jQuery supports [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on), so it does the checks for you. But I'm not immediately sure that applies to what you're doing.
2. If for some reason you couldn't use that, jQuery's `closest` would probably help:

   ```
   if (!$(e.target).closest(".menu-area")[0]) {
       closeMenu();
   }
   ```

   [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) tests the element against a selector and, if it doesn't match, checks its parent node, and so on. The `[0]` at the end tells us whether jQuery found anything. In the above, if it *didn't* find anything (the `!` at the beginning), we close the menu.